# What is the best way to write Model code in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am very much confused regarding which technique to use to code Model in codeigniter.

I searched a lot and found various methods used by various coders. Kindly guide me the best way to write Model Class using codeigniter.

Few examples;

- Some take long parameters in Method signature

  ```
   function insert_data($name, $address, $email, $....,$...,$..)
  ```

  While others just use the following and write all post code inside
  Model..

  ```
  function insert()
  { 
  $name= $this->input->post('var1');
  $name= $this->input->post('var1');
  $name= $this->input->post('var1');
  }
  ```
- Some create different Model for each Table,  while some write very few Models..

  And many more contradictions between different developers, 
  I am so much confused in which technique to use to write  more efficient
  and industry standard code.

  Kindly guide me Thanks a lot

Comment: Use this Base model for your all models [link](https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model). It is good practice to create model for each table

Comment: Thanks, and Where to write user input code i.e `$this->input->post` ; in model or in Controller?

Comment: $_GET and $_POST should be handled in controller

Comment: So if i am inserting data then my Method parameters list will be very large in number e.g: `function insert data($id,$name $age, $email, $....)`                                                                                                            These all values will be passed from Controller to Model

Comment: If you use this Base Model [link](https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model#synopsis)   then you have to call only this function `$this->post->insert(array(
    'status' => 'open',
    'title' => "my title"
));` n number of parameters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a good question. It goes back on the pros and cons of Codeigniter. Being that you can customize Codeitgniter as much as you wish (which a lot of people overdo), issues like these come up, where its up to the developer to decide where things belong. With that being said, I will share how I use models.

According to Codeigniter's MVC standards:

> The Model represents your data structures. Typically your model
>   classes will contain functions that help you retrieve, insert, and
>   update information in your database.

Therefore a model should only handle the communication with your database, or if you don't use databases, it should handle the retrieval of data from other sources (i.e. json, text files, etc...).

What I recommend:

- Keep all your internal functionalities in your controller method, this includes all your `$this->input->post()` information. Once you have all your `post()` information, create the necessary array and pass it to the model
- The model, should receive the array (which you constructed in your controller) and build the database queries needed to retrieve the information.

With this structure, you may reuse these model methods from any controllers, keeping a modular structure.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

this might help you. (how i use model in codeigniter)

MY MODEL PHP FILE:

```
<?php

class Dbmodel extends CI_Model {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->db->query("SET time_zone='+05:30'");
}

function customQueryInsert($table, $array_data, $array_condition) {
    if (!empty($array_condition)) {
        $this->db->where($array_condition);
    }
    $result = $this->db->insert($table, $array_data);
    if ($result) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

function customQueryInsertGetId($table, $array_data, $array_condition) {
    if (!empty($array_condition)) {
        $this->db->where($array_condition);
    }
    $result = $this->db->insert($table, $array_data);
    if ($result) {
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

function lastQuery() {
    return $this->db->last_query();
}
}
```

AND CALLING IN CONTROLLER:

```
$this->load->model('Dbmodel', 'Dbmodel', TRUE);
$this->notification = $this->Dbmodel->customQuerySingleResult("select count(id) as ncount from notification where id='$this->id' and status='unread'", "ncount");
$this->Dbmodel->customQueryInsert("activity", array('userid' => $this->id, 'username' => $this->email, 'activity' => uri_string()), array());
```

this is how i use MODEL in CODEIGNITER.. in your case you can use below code to insert your data, assuming you are writing it inside a controller method.

```
$this->load->model('Dbmodel', 'Dbmodel', TRUE);
$status = $this->Dbmodel->customQueryInsert("table_name",array('column_name'=>'var1','column_two'=>'var2'));
if($status){
  //do succes stuffs
}else{
  //fail redirect...
}
```

now you dont need to create methods with required parameters.. just call `customQueryInsert` method and pass table name as first parameter and array of `column_name=>column_data` to second parameter...

you can optimize it according to your need.. or if you want further help please let me know..

Comment: I think that lots of code does not explain the answer. It will be better if you describe the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to http://www.codeigniter.com/ at the bottom you will see

> CodeIgniter encourages MVC, but does not force it on you.

1. It means you can write your code as you want.

From your example

`function insert_data($name, $address, $email, $....,$...,$..)` is better way than `function insert()`. 1st one is reusable.

Suppose you want do same task using get method.In that case you need to write another insert function for get.but 1st one can be reused if you pass them from your controller.

2. `$this->input->post` better way to use this function at controller.If you use it at model's function that means that function will only work where there must be post data.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Doctor extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('doctor_model');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }
    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */
    public function index()
    {



        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'required');
         if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) { 
           $data = array(
               'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
               'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
               'password' => $this->input->post('password')
              );

                $this->doctor_model->add('doctor',$data);
         } 
         else { 

         } 
        $this->load->view('doctor_reg');


    }


public function login()
    {
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'required');
         if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) { 
           $data = array(
               'email' => $this->input->post('email'),

                      );
            $email = $this->input->post('email');

              $logindata= $this->doctor_model->get_row('doctor','email',$email);


             if($logindata){

              $sess_array = array(
                       'id' => $logindata->id,
                       'name' => $logindata->name,
                       'email' => $logindata->email
       );

              $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
               redirect('doctor-dashboard');

             }


    }

   $this->load->view('doctor_login');


}

public function dashboard()
    {
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $d_id=$session_data['id'];
         //$c_record['schdule']=$this->doctor_model->get_entry_by_data('schedule',false,array('d_id'=>$d_id));
         $c_record['schdule']=$this->doctor_model->get_data_by_join('schedule', 'clinik', array('schedule.d_id'=>$d_id), 'c_id', 'c_id');



        $this->load->view('dashboard',$c_record);
    }

public function add_clinick()
    {
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $d_id=$session_data['id'];
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('c_name', 'c_name', 'required');
         if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) { 

           $data = array(
               'c_name'  => $this->input->post('c_name'),
               'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
                'd_id'   => $d_id
              );

                $add=$this->doctor_model->add('clinik',$data);

                if($add){
                    redirect('doctor-dashboard');
                }
         } 
         else { 

         }
        $this->load->view('add_clinick');
    }

public function add_schedule(){

        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $d_id=$session_data['id'];
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $d_id=$session_data['id'];
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('clinick', 'clinick', 'required');
         if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) { 

       $data = array(
                'd_id'  => $d_id,
                'c_id'  => $this->input->post('clinick'),
                'day' => $this->input->post('day'),
                'fron_time'   => $this->input->post('f_time'),
                'to_time'   => $this->input->post('t_time')
              );
       $fron_time=$this->input->post('f_time');
       $to_time=$this->input->post('t_time');
        $c_id= $this->input->post('clinick');
           $day = $this->input->post('day');


 //$btwn='d_id='.$d_id.' day='.$day.' AND fron_time  BETWEEN '.$fron_time.' AND '.$to_time.' AND fron_time  BETWEEN '.$fron_time.' AND '.$to_time;

$wh= "d_id='".$d_id."' AND day='".$day."' AND (fron_time  BETWEEN '".$fron_time."' AND '".$to_time."' OR to_time  BETWEEN '".$fron_time."' AND '".$to_time."')";


   $ntbetwn=$this->doctor_model->get_entry_by_data('schedule',false,$wh);
   //echo $this->db->last_query();

// $c_record['schdule']=$this->doctor_model->get_entry_by_data('schedule',false,array('d_id'=>$d_id));
if($ntbetwn==''){
           $s_records = $this->doctor_model->add('schedule',$data);


               if( $s_records){

                     redirect('doctor-dashboard');
                }
}
else{
    $massage='you already schedule this time';
    $c_record['massage']=$massage;
            } 
       }


      //$c_record['clinick']= $this->doctor_model->get_row('clinik','c_id',$d_id);


      $c_record['clinick']=$this->doctor_model->get_entry_by_data('clinik',false,array('d_id'=>$d_id));

  $this->load->view('add_schedule',$c_record);


}

}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Code-only answers are discouraged. Please improve your answer by explaining you solution and giving more context that may be helpful for a potential reader.

Answer (score 0):

model example

```
<?php 
class Doctor_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    public function add($table,$data)
    {
        return $this->db->insert($table, $data);

    }



    public function get_data($table,$primaryfield,$fieldname,$id)
    {
        $this->db->select($fieldname);
        $this->db->where($primaryfield,$id);
        $q = $this->db->get($table);
        if($q->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return $q->result();
        }
        return array();
    }


     public function get_row($table,$primaryfield,$id)
    {
        $this->db->where($primaryfield,$id);
        $q = $this->db->get($table);
        if($q->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return $q->row();
        }
        return false;
    }





function get_entry_by_data($table_name, $single = false, $data = array(), $select = "", $order_by = '', $orderby_field = '', $limit = '', $offset = 0, $group_by = '') {

            if (!empty($select)) {
                $this->db->select($select);
            }

            if (empty($data)) {

                $id = $this->input->post('id');

                if (!$id)
                    return false;

                $data = array('id' => $id);
            }
            if (!empty($group_by)) {

                $this->db->group_by($group_by);
            }


            if (!empty($limit)) {
                $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
            }

            if (!empty($order_by) && !empty($orderby_field)) {

                $this->db->order_by($orderby_field, $order_by);
            }

            $query = $this->db->get_where($table_name, $data);

            $res = $query->result_array();

            //echo $this->db->last_query();exit;

            if (!empty($res)) {

                if ($single)
                    return $res[0];
                else
                    return $res;
            } else
                return false;
        }


    public function get_entry_by_data_in($table_name, $single = false, $data = array(), $select = "", $order_by = '', $orderby_field = '', $limit = '', $offset = 0, $group_by = '',$in_column='',$in_data=''){



            if (!empty($select)) {
                $this->db->select($select);
            }

            if (empty($data)) {

                $id = $this->input->post('id');

                if (!$id)
                    return false;

                $data = array('id' => $id);
            }
            if (!empty($group_by)) {

                $this->db->group_by($group_by);
            }


            if (!empty($limit)) {
                $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
            }

            if (!empty($order_by) && !empty($orderby_field)) {

                $this->db->order_by($orderby_field, $order_by);
            }

            if (!empty($in_data) and !empty($in_column)) {
               $this->db->where_in($in_column,$in_data);
            }

            $query = $this->db->get_where($table_name, $data);

            $res = $query->result_array();

            //echo $this->db->last_query();exit;

            if (!empty($res)) {

                if ($single)
                    return $res[0];
                else
                    return $res;
            } else
                return false;

    }
        public function getAllRecords($table, $orderby_field = '', $orderby_val = '', $where_field = '', $where_val = '', $select = '', $limit = '', $limit_val = '') {

            if (!empty($limit)) {
                $offset = (empty($limit_val)) ? '0' : $limit_val;
                $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
            }
            if (!empty($select)) {

                $this->db->select($select);
            }
            if ($orderby_field)
                $this->db->order_by($orderby_field, $orderby_val);

            if ($where_field)
                $this->db->where($where_field, $where_val);

            $query = $this->db->get($table);

            //return $query->num_rows;
            //echo $this->db->last_query();
            if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
                return $query->result_array();
            }
        }

        function alldata($table) {
            $query = $this->db->get($table);
            return $query->result_array();
        }

        function alldata_count($table, $where) {
            $query = $this->db->get_where($table, $where);
            return $query->num_rows();
        }

        function insert_entry($table, $data) {
            $this->db->insert($table, $data);
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }



        function update_entry($table_name, $data, $where) {
            return $this->db->update($table_name, $data, $where);
        }

      public function get_data_by_join($table, $table2, $where, $table1_column, $table2_column, $limit = '', $order_column = '', $order_by = 'DESC', $select_columns = '', $is_single_record = false, $group_by = '', $join_by = '', $offset = '') {
            if (!empty($select_columns)) {
                $this->db->select($select_columns);
            } else {
                $this->db->select('*');
            }

            $this->db->from($table);
            $this->db->join($table2, $table . '.' . $table1_column . '=' . $table2 . '.' . $table2_column, $join_by);
            $this->db->where($where);
            if (!empty($limit)) {
                if (!empty($offset)) {
                    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
                } else {
                    $this->db->limit($limit);
                }
            }
            if (!empty($order_column)) {
                $this->db->order_by($order_column, $order_by);
            }

            if (!empty($group_by)) {
                $this->db->group_by($group_by);
            }

            $query = $this->db->get();
            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

                if ($is_single_record) {
                    $rs = $query->result_array();
                    return $rs[0];
                } else {
                    return $query->result_array();
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        function DeleteRecord($table_name, $where) {
            return $this->db->delete($table_name, $where);
        }

        function managerecord() {
            $count = 1;
            $where = array('channel_id' => 8,
                'field_id_12 !=' => '');
            $this->db->where($where);
            $query = $this->db->get('channel_data');
            $data = $query->result_array();
            foreach ($data as $value) {
                $id = $value['field_id_12'];
                $update = array('telephone' => $value['field_id_53'],
                    'about' => $value['field_id_54'],
                    'license' => $value['field_id_18'],
                    'broker' => $value['field_id_19'],
                    'preferred' => 'yes');
                $this->db->update('members', $update, array('member_id' => $id));
            }
            echo "done1";
        }

        public function get_content_landing_page($table = false, $field = false, $id = false, $id_name = false) {
            $this->db->select($field);
            $this->db->from($table);
            $this->db->where($id_name, $id);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result_array();
        }

        public function get_field_landing_page($id = false,$fields=false) {
            $this->db->select($fields);
            $this->db->from('terratino_form_fields_master');
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result_array();
        }




}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for offering an answer. Can you share a bit more of why you propose this code snippet?