# load multiple query result to the view

Tags: codeigniter

I fetch data from the database and have to show it in my view part and actually, I don't know how to get my fetched data in my VIEW?

And also don't create controller properly,  so what is remaining in my controller?

This is the models

```
public function getPlanById($planId){    
    $this->db->where('plan_id', $planId);           
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_plan');       
 }

public function getPlanAndTaskMappingByPlanId($planId){
    $this->db->where('plan_id', $planId);
    $query = $this->db->get('plan_task_mapping');
    return $query->result();    
}    

public function getAllVeddingTask(){        
    $query = $this->db->get('vedd_plan_task');
    return $query->result();
}
```

and the controller is

```
$veddingPlanData = $this->PlanModel->getPlanById($planId);  
$veddingPlanTaskMappingData = $this->PlanModel->getPlanAndTaskMappingByPlanId($planId);
$allVedingTasks = $this->VeddingTaskModel->getAllVeddingTask();
```

---

I have asked this question when i stared to learn Codeigniter. 
So I like to add the correct way to load query resul to the view.Pass the query result to the controller and then to load thet view:

```
public function controller_function(){
    $veddingPlanData = $this->PlanModel->getPlanById($planId);   
    $veddingPlanTaskMappingData = $this->PlanModel->getPlanAndTaskMappingByPlanId($planId);
    $allVedingTasks = $this->VeddingTaskModel->getAllVeddingTask();

    $this->load->view('your_view',['veddingPlanData' => $veddingPlanData, 
    'veddingPlanTaskMappingData'=>$veddingPlanTaskMappingData,
    'allVedingTasks'=>$allVedingTasks
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation? http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you've to adapt your models - below i'll show you an example

```
public function getPlanById($planId)
{

    $this->db->where('plan_id', $planId);
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_plan');

    $arrData = array();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach($query->result() AS $row)
        {
            $arrData[] = $row;
        }
    }

    return $arrData;
}

public function getPlanAndTaskMappingByPlanId($planId)
{
    $this->db->where('plan_id', $planId);
    $query = $this->db->get('plan_task_mapping');

    $arrData = array();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach($query->result() AS $row)
        {
            $arrData[] = $row;
        }
    }

    return $arrData;
}


public function getAllVeddingTask()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('vedd_plan_task');
    $arrData = array();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach($query->result() AS $row)
        {
            $arrData[] = $row;
        }
    }

    return $arrData;
}
```

now your controller should look like

```
class YourController extends CI_Controller
{
    public function your_method()
    {
        $this->load->model("PlanModel");
        $this->load->model("VeddingTaskModel");

        $arrViewData = array(
            "arrVeddingPlanData" => $this->PlanModel->getPlanById($planId),
            "arrVeddingPlanTaskMappingData" => $this->PlanModel->getPlanAndTaskMappingByPlanId($planId),
            "arrAllVedingTasks" => $this->VeddingTaskModel->getAllVeddingTask()
        );


        $this->load->view("yourview", $arrViewData);
    }
}
```

and finally an example for your view

```
foreach($arrVeddingPlanData AS $objWeddingPlan)
{
    var_dump($objWeddingPlan);
}
```

besides of the given exmaple i strongly recommend - instead of returning just a result in your models you should prepare the Data for your needs in the model and return an array of data to the passing controller

Comment: Message: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')

Comment: i just got the plan data i have to show the mapped data form task table how to get it??

Comment: there is another Variable called `arrVeddingPlanTaskMappingData`
just print that out in the same way like the arrVeddingPlanData 
(just take a look at my controller example - 3 Variables getting passed to your view)

Answer (score 3):

Update your controller to following code

```
$data['veddingPlanData'] = $this->PlanModel->getPlanById($planId);
$data['veddingPlanTaskMappingData'] = $this->PlanModel->getPlanAndTaskMappingByPlanId($planId);
$data['allVedingTasks'] = $this->VeddingTaskModel->getAllVeddingTask();

$this->load->view('front/view', $data);
```

**replace** `'front/view'` with path/name of you view file.

**To access data**, in your view file `var_dump()` or `print_r()` the variables `$veddingPlanData`, `$veddingPlanTaskMappingData` or `$allVedingTasks`

Comment: actually this is the data which i fetch form database ,, so in view i have to show this data in the input box...means how to use "foreach" for getting this data???

Comment: @ankitsuthar you will receive array in your view against each variable. To see what is in array you can use `print_r($veddingPlanData);` in your view.

Comment: ok i got in array but i have to use foreach loop for displaying this fetched data...  hop u understand  .. thx

Comment: @ankitsuthar yes, you have to use `loop` for it. Please accept my answer if you found it useful.

Comment: @ankitsuthar accepting an answer will not take more then 1 second of you.

Answer (score 1):

as i am not able to comment

first try to `var_dump($veddingPlanTaskMappingData)` `var_dump($allVedingTasks)` and check what you are getting from database..

also try this link, it will help you to implement what you are looking for:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31115876/5058701

UPDATE: (as you want to foreach data in view)::

```
//in your model:
function QueryResult($customQuery) {
    $query = $this->db->query($customQuery);
    if (!$query) {
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

//in your controller
$this->load->model("Model_Name","ShortName",true);
$data['arr'] = $this->ShortName->QueryResult("select col1,col2 from table where id=2");
$this->load->view('welcome', $data);

//in your welcome view: assuming you only have 2 inputs box and one row in database for that two input boxes
foreach($data['arr'] as $arr){
  echo "<input type='text' name='col1' value='$arr->col1'>";
  echo "<input type='text' name='col2' value='$arr->col2'>";
}
```

hope this helps...

Comment: Even if you cannot comment do not post comment as answer.Try other area and get some repu and do comment.

Comment: @shaifullslam i am here to help and not to earn repu.. but my repu is not enough that does not mean i should not help where i can help..